# How can I test for the correlation between a spatial distance matrix and a species co-occurrence distance matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I want to test whether there is a correlation between the spatial distances of 18 plots and the dissimilarity in their species composition. I also have information about whether they are urban (as a binary distance matrix).

I thought I could use a mantel's test but after doing some readings I think this would be inappropriate due to the spatial autocorrelation of my distance matrix. I was also hoping there might be a way to run a linear model with matrices and include whether or not the two plots are urban as a factor in the model.

Could someone please point me towards a method (preferably R based) that I could look into? I've never worked with matrices before so recommendations for basic intro books with R code would also be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that dbRDA (distance based Redundance Analysis) can solve your problem. You need a Y-variable (dissimilarity matrix of your species composition) and two X-variables (Lat and Long, in this case you don't need a spatial distance matrix, you use your coordinates). If you want, you can use more X-variables too, maybe ecological variables.

R use `capscale()` function of **VEGAN** package to do dbRDA. Then you can use `anova()` and `RsquareAdj()` or `plot()` to explore your results (dbRDA object) and the importance of your variables to explain your species differences between your plots.